# Delete a S3 file using WSO2 ESB S3 connector

Tags: amazon-s3, wso2, esb

I am running into issues while trying to delete a file that resides in Amazon S3 using the WSO2 ESB connector. Here is what I have done:
1) Created a proxy service in WSO2 ESB using the following taken from the [WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Objects+in+Amazon+S3#WorkingwithObjectsinAmazonS3-deleteObject) :

2) I made sure that the proxy service is deployed to WSO2 then using POSTMAN 
3) I submitted the following to POSTMAN:

```
<deleteObject>
<accessKeyId>MYACCESSKEY</accessKeyId>
<secretAccessKey>MYSECRETKEY</secretAccessKey>
<methodType>DELETE</methodType>
<contentType>application/xml</contentType>
<expect>100-continue</expect>
<region>us-east-1</region>
<host>s3.amazonaws.com</host>
<bucketUrl>http://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET</bucketUrl>
<bucketName>MYBUCKET</bucketName>
<isXAmzDate>true</isXAmzDate>
<objectName>FILETODELETE.txt</objectName>
<versionId></versionId>
</deleteObject>
```

I get the following error message (beginning of message):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature  you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>MYACCESSKEY</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
Sat, 07 Jul 2018 15:25:18 GMT
20180707/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
618b0c822492e3dd2a8f4d9e1ea</StringToSign>   <SignatureProvided>06b2b268cb90b69a1c5dadbb689ed4ccf7b459ff1b5</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>BUNCH OF NUMBERS</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>DELETE
/MYBUCKET/xxxxx.txt/

content-type:application/xml
host:s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:Sat, 07 Jul 2018 15:25:18 GMT
content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>BUNCH OF NUMBERS</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>SOODEDIBD</RequestId>
  <HostId>vLllBSaWMHkV+gqX6yh7+43WK4PsAO4VVXLdGePBvGWZtxxExbBqI=</HostId>
```

I recreated my S3 credentials, but I am still running into the same error, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Frank

Comment: The bucket name inside 
both  `<bucketUrl>http://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET</bucketUrl>` and `<bucketName>MYBUCKET</bucketName>` seems redundant.  Remove the bucket name from `<bucketUrl>`.

Comment: How are you trying to call the web service?is it http or https ? if https then you first need to know If certificate is required to be installed in wso2 before calling the service,By the error message it looks like there is certificate issue,If you are unable to figure out then try taking a TCPDUMP so that it will be clear whether the communication is happening or not

Answer (score 0):

After going through delete object for S3, you need to check if the header values are going proper or not, as there is authentication required before accessing the web service , The header should look something like this .

```
DELETE /my-image.jpg?versionId=3HL4kqCxf3vjVBH40Nrjfkd HTTPS/1.1
Host: bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-mfa: 20899872 301749
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2009 22:32:00 GMT
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:0RQf4/cRonhpaBX5sCYVf1bNRuU=
```

You can put wso2 esb on debug mode and confirm where proper header is being passed or not, else take a TCPDUMP to be accurate